# How do I get a working MySQL database from my web server to my newly installed WAMP

Tags: php, mysql

Please be gentle.  I'm a newbie and I did search here and in Google for this problem but I can't find anything close.  I built a DB on my Web Server and was doing great entering all my records.  For the past week the Web Server claims they have been being spammed and I keep getting time outs and page load errors.  In my 'brilliance' I thought it would be simple to install WAMP on my computer, get the DB, populate it on my computer and upload it when I was done.

I was able to install the WAMP.  However, I have absolutely no clue how to get the DB here, or where to put it or how to get it working in my testing server for Dreamweaver.  I tried an export from the Web Server but that only gave me a tiny ***.sql file that can't possibly have all the 1700+ records I've already entered.

Can anyone please tell me where there might be instructions how to do this?  As I said I've been searching and searching and the best I found was to go from one Web Server to another.  But that won't work for me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Open the `phpMyAdmin` on your WAMP server, and import the sql file. Also, there must be an option on your Web Server to export the file + data, if its not already doing that.

Comment: Embarrased as I am I think you're right.  I thought the export was only 294 bites.  I just checked and it's 294 KB which certainly could be the whole thing, so far.  I didn't know hot to get it into my system but it would appear you have just told me how.

Comment: Also, if you're importing a large file, you could zip it and then import it, in `phpMyAdmin`.

Comment: I'm afraid this is going to take some time.  I already have the file on my hard drive in 'my downloads.'  I can't log into phpMyAdmin.  It's telling me   The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>  but the link doesn't work. I have to find out what they are saying.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @John Bupit Thank you Thank you and Thank you.  It was a problem getting around that error but I made it.  Then I had a lot of learning to do but I made it through the rain now all I have to do is figure out what I need to do to my code to write to the local server instead of the web server.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Obtain a mysql dump of your database. Then import it into your new database.

Here are the shell commands.

Run this one on the server with the working database.

`$ mysqldump -u *username* -p *password* -h localhost *DB_NAME* > /path/to/output/file.sql`

Run this on your machine with WAMP.

`$ mysql -u *username* -p *password* -h localhost *DB_NAME* < /path/to/dump/file.sql`

Comment: `$ mysql ... *DB_NAME* < /path/to/dump/file.sql`